# Linker Option with 1.0 in name Windows

Tags: gcc, mingw-w64, libusb, linkage, libusb-1.0

I am trying to create a program using the libusb-1.0 library
After I installed the library when I try to compile like so

`gcc -g main.c -o test.exe -lusb-1.0` 
i get the following error
`gcc.exe: error: .0: No such file or directory`

what do I have to type for the linkage option "-lusb-1.0" to be read properly

I am using mingw64 on Windows

Comment: Are you sure there's no space between `1` and `.0`?

Comment: And do you really know what the `-g` option does?

Comment: Yes there was no space.
However, when I compile from cmd instead of the powershell terminal inside VSC, i no longer get this error.
there was a typo, the second flag should be -o

Comment: Perhaps it's a PowrrShell issue? Can you replicate it using other commands? Might want to [edit] this question, or post a new one, about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by adding single or double quotes around '-lusb-1.0'

for example here is the code i used to compile

`gcc *.c -o test.exe '-lusb-1.0'`